# preventDefault() was working properly, now only works intermittently

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

In my app I have been using preventDefault() for a few years to use my custom pop up to appear on a right click.

In my init function:

```
element.contextmenu(getRightClickOrd.bind(this));
```

and

```
function getRightClickOrd(mouseEvent) {
"use strict";
   var widgetId = mouseEvent.target.parentNode.id;

   //prevent default contextmenu appearing
   mouseEvent.preventDefault();
   mouseEvent.stopPropagation();

   customPopup(widgetId, "command");
}
```

Now it only works intermittently, with both the default menu and my custom pop up both appearing sometimes.

Comment: Hi!  I'd suggest a few questions: what has changed recently? as in, when you noticed this happening, what had changed? Program / script wise, as well as maybe browser updates.  Maybe another element is raising the default menu event?

Comment: Try adding adding the .preventDefault() at the top:

function getRightClickOrd(mouseEvent) {
   //prevent default contextmenu appearing
   mouseEvent.preventDefault();
   mouseEvent.stopPropagation();
"use strict";
   var widgetId = mouseEvent.target.parentNode.id;

   customPopup(widgetId, "command");
}